# PHP using Declare ? What is a tick?

Tags: php, declare

I am a little bit confused by the PHP function `declare`.

What exactly is a single tick? I thought a tick equals one line of code?

But if I use:

```
function myfunc() {
        print "Tick";   
}

register_tick_function("myfunc");

declare(ticks=1) {
   echo 'foo!bar';
}
```

The script prints:

"Tick" 2 Times??

Comment: For the record, the documentation is https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You get a tick for each line ; and each block {}
Try that:

```
declare(ticks=1) echo 'foo!bar';
```

No block, no extra tick.

```
declare(ticks=1) {{ echo 'foo!bar'; }}
```

More extraneous blocks = more ticks.

PS: by the way, ticks are quite the exotic feature and they're only useful in a few *extremely rare* situations. They are not equivalent to threading or anything. If, for you, ticks are the solution to a problem then you should post about your problem in another question because it's probably not the right solution to it.

Comment: What *can* ticks be useful for?

Comment: @thomasrutter How? Could you please give an example or a reference?

Comment: pcntl_signal_dispatch(); or ticks = 1;
That's both a method to allow signal handling within the php script.

Answer (score 17):

You are on the right track as to what a tick is.

https://web.archive.org/web/20100801093511/http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/21/0

> Put simply, a tick is a special event
> that occurs internally in PHP each
> time it has executed a certain number
> of statements. These statements are
> internal to PHP and loosely correspond
> to the statements in your script. You
> can control how many statements it
> takes to set off a tick using the
> declare() function, and you can
> register functions to execute when a
> tick occurs by using the
> register_tick_function() function. As
> mentioned already, the syntax for
> declare is very unusual, so be ready
> for a shock!

Comment: Thanks.  I found it odd that php.net manual didn't define ticks in declare() and the *_tick_function() functions.  Do you know why they are being removed in PHP6?

Comment: How did ticks even get in PHP?

Comment: @Jayrox - Any supportive evidence to support your statement "PHP6 ticks will be removed completely" theory?

Comment: @Jimbo: The only reference i found regarding this was http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/21/0

Comment: If ticks are going away, what's replacing them?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for *"Note that in PHP7 ticks will be removed completely"* ??? As far as I'm aware this is not true.

Comment: PHP 7 is out and ticks are still in