# how can i set a tick_func() for all functions?

Tags: php

How can I set the **tick_func** for **all function**

```
function tick_func(){    //for all func,
  sleep(1);
}

//sample function    
call_any_func();              // this will wait 1 sec.
call_another_func();          // this will wait 1 sec.
```

Comment: I want to slow down to 1000 over,  function....  
function sample_handler(){  if function sleep(1);
}

Comment: Are you trying to execute `all_func_sleep()` after every time you call any other function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, all I can think to point you to is [register_tick_function()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) as possibly what you're trying to do:

```
declare(ticks=1);

// using a function as the callback
register_tick_function('all_func_sleep', true);

// your code here...

unregister_tick_function('all_func_sleep');
```

As Matchu says below, this will call after every statement, instead of on function calls, but if you minimize the amount of code between the register... and unregister_tick_function() calls, you can approximate this functionality.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ticks, and [the PHP docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks) don't offer fantastic examples. What does this *do*, exactly?

Comment: A little more information is offered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441479/php-using-declare-what-is-a-tick) (pointing [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/21/0))

Comment: @Problematic: interesting feature. I don't think it *quite* meets the OP's requirements, since it seems like it will run after each statement instead of each function call, but, given the unclear question, who knows? +1

Comment: @Matchu: True, but if he has a finite amount of work that he needs to do, and can put it in a loop (or even just procedurally), he can delimit the workspace with `unregister_tick_function()`. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Does a tick run on statements inside functions called within the declared zone, or just on the outermost level of the stack?

Answer (score 4):

Given your [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310133/how-do-i-set-up-the-a-function-for-all-functions-before-or-after) in addition to this post, I think I get what you want to do: run a function before or after *every other function* in the entire script.

PHP does not offer this functionality. You must manually type this function call at the start or end of any function you wish to affect.

```
<?php
function some_func_sleep() {
    sleep(1);
}

function call_any_func() {
    some_func_sleep();
    // whatever you actually want it to do
}

function call_another_func() {
    some_func_sleep();
    // whatever other thing you want it to do
}

call_any_func();
call_another_func();
```

Ta da. It's not exactly beautiful, but it's clear.