# kill is absorbed by "system" call and never triggers pcntl_signal

Tags: php, pcntl

I have a daemon script and I'm trying to keep it simple by avoiding threads.

When i ctrl-c or kill pid, the "system" call is exited, but exitFunction isn't called.

```
declare(ticks = 100);

function exitFunction($signo) {
    global $pidFile, $exit;
    unlink($pidFile);
    echo "Daemon is exiting (signal: $signo). Removing pidFile: $pidFile\n";
    $exit = true;
};
//create the signal handler and shutdown function
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "exitFunction");
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "exitFunction");

//create the pid file with our command
file_put_contents($pidFile, posix_getpid());

echo "pid: " . posix_getpid() . "\n";
echo "Time to start!\n";
while(!$exit) {
    echo "running $command...\n";
    system($command, $return);
    echo "done $command\n";
    if($return) {
        echo "didn't find any domains with command, so sleeping for 60...\n";
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `declare(ticks=1);` as the first line in your script?

Comment: i changed it to 100 as some random suggestion had. I'm assuming this simply affects the speed at which the handler gets called. I've edited my question. Perhaps it NEEDS to be 1?

Comment: ok that worked, lol.

Comment: I'm back to my original problem, but I'll make a new question for that one.
Do you want to make a quick answer about ticks=1? So i cna accept it, or shall I?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879460/kill-exits-system-call-before-triggering-pcntl-signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add `declare(ticks=1);` as the first line in your script. A more detailed explanation of what ticks actually are can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441479/php-using-declare-what-is-a-tick).