# kill exits system call before triggering pcntl_signal

Tags: php

I have a daemon script I made and when i ctrl-c my signal is called, but not before my "system" call immediately exits. The whole point of me handling the signals is to let the "system" call finish gracefully before exiting the infinite loop.
How can i stop kill commands from exiting my system call?

```
declare(ticks=1)

function exitFunction($signo) {
    global $pidFile, $exit;
    unlink($pidFile);
    echo "Daemon is exiting (signal: $signo). Removing pidFile: $pidFile\n";
    $exit = true;
};
//create the signal handler and shutdown function
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, "exitFunction");
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "exitFunction");

//create the pid file with our command
file_put_contents($pidFile, posix_getpid());

echo "pid: " . posix_getpid() . "\n";
echo "Time to start!\n";
while(!$exit) {
    echo "running $command...\n";
    system($command, $return);
    echo "done $command\n";
    if($return) {
        echo "didn't find any domains with command, so sleeping for 60...\n";
        sleep(60);
    }
}
```

Note: If it's impossible to handle signals from "system" without forking, then let me know and I'll use forking. I'm avoiding forking, because IMO it makes the logic more complicated, so given the serial nature of my daemon I figured I'd be wise to avoid it.

EDIT: realized ctrl-c is different from kill. If I use kill, then everything works as expected, but if I ctrl-c my system call dies regardless of catching the signal (note: the signal IS still triggered by a ctrl-c).

Comment: Keyboard signals are sent to all processes in the process group. You need to fork and use `posix_setsid()`, so that `system()` runs in a different process group.

Comment: That explains it! Thanks. This would be the answer... I simply can't do what i want without forking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible without forking.