# Bug in PHP sockets? It does not obey timeout

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, server

I start the following server:

```
<?php

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,  SOL_TCP);

socket_bind($socket, 'localhost', 9000) or die("Failed: socket_bind()");
socket_listen($socket, 20)              or die("Failed: socket_listen()");

$client = socket_accept($socket);

socket_set_option($client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec'=>1, 'usec'=>0));
socket_set_option($client, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array('sec'=>1, 'usec'=>0));

while(1) {
  $read = array($client);
  $write = $except = null;
  socket_select($read,$write,$except,1);
}
```

When I try connect to this server with `telnet localhost 9000` it does not exit after a second, despite I have set 1 sec timeout.

PHP 7.0.11 on Linux. There is a similar problem with PHP 5.6.21 on FreeBSD

Why does it not work?

Note: In this example I try to *decrease* the timeout. In my real problem I need to increase it to a few hours or maybe few days.

Comment: possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441479/php-using-declare-what-is-a-tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason it should exit. As far as I understand your code:

- You are setting the timeout for read and write operations, but you don't do any read or writes in the code shown.
- You are calling select with a timeout of 1 and once select is done you call it again etc in an endless loop.